# Cannot Show Databases in CnosDB

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

Following this [QuickStart](https://docs.cnosdb.com/guide/quick_start.html) doc, I created a database but couldn't see it coming up in the query.

Details are:

```
docker run -itd  --env cpu=2 --env memory=4 -p 31007:31007 cnosdb/cnosdb

docker exec -it <container_id> sh

$ cnosdb-cli
CREATE DATABASE oceanic_station;
show databases;
SHOW DATABASES;
```

The error message:

> ? show databases;
> "{"error_code":"0100000","error_message":"Error executiong
> query: Failed to do execute statement, err:Failed to do parse. err:
> sql parser error: Expected tables/databases, found: databases"}"
>
> ❯ SHOW DATABASES; "error sending request for url
> (http://0.0.0.0:31007/api/v1/sql?db=public): connection closed before
> message completed"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

docker versions may behind stable releases versions

Comment: unfortunately you are right. I was pulling the latest which gave the obsolete version. If I specify the version in the image as cnosdb/cnosdb/v2.0.0, that works like a charm.